# Error when sending an external request from AWS through Node.js and Axios

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I'm having a strange problem when making a request
Error log AWS

```
AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

2022-12-15T12:46:48.592+02:00

Copy
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {

2022-12-15T12:46:48.592+02:00   port: 80,

2022-12-15T12:46:48.592+02:00   address: '127.0.0.1',

2022-12-15T12:46:48.592+02:00

Copy
  syscall: 'connect',
syscall: 'connect',

2022-12-15T12:46:48.592+02:00   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
```

Everything goes ok on the local server, but on the aws server I can't make a request in an external endpoint

```
await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url,
                auth: {
                     "username": process.env.ENV == 'Production' ? `${process.env.prod_url}` : `${process.env.dev_url}`,
                                "password": process.env.ENV == 'Production' ? `${process.env.prod_pass}` : `${process.env.dev_pass}`
                            },
                data: {
                    "root": {
                        "head": {
                            "auth": {
                                "username": process.env.ENV == 'Production' ? `${process.env.prod_url}` : `${process.env.dev_url}`,
                                "password": process.env.ENV == 'Production' ? `${process.env.prod_pass}` : `${process.env.dev_pass}`
                            },
                            "service": service
                        },
                        "main": mainJSON
                    }
                },
                httpsAgent: new Agent({
                    rejectUnauthorized: false,
                })
            })
```

The configuration is on a docker image in node.. So I don't know what it could be
If I make a request in my database everything is ok, but only when I make a request with axios in another endpoint, this happens

Comment: The error messages say `127.0.0.1:80`. Are you connecting to yourself? Is there a web server running locally on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect to localhost on port 80. If that is the intended target, ensure that you have a web server running on that port.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

If localhost is not your intended target, change the url to the external one which you are trying to reach ensuring your security groups allow traffic on that port.